# variable access outside of if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to access variable outside an if statement in java. The variable is `axeMinDmg`. Here is what i have but getting an error. I want `minDmg = axeMinDmg`. thanks

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
        {


            int count = 1;

    // start both with 1 point  
    int goodTotal = 50;
    int monTotal = 50;

    // set amount of money that Goodman has
    int moneyAmt = 10;




    // setting array for bat

    int [] bat = {2, 4, 3};
    int batMinDmg = bat[0];
    int batMaxDmg = bat[1];
    int batCost = bat[2];

    //setting array for axe
    int [] axe = {4, 6, 6};
    int axeMinDmg = axe[0];
    int axeMaxDmg = axe[1];
    int axeCost = axe[2];

    //setting array for sword

    int [] sword = {6, 8, 10};
    int swordMinDmg = sword[0];
    int swordMaxDmg = sword[1];
    int swordCost = sword[2];



   // ask if Goodman would like to purchase a weapon   
   System.out.println("Would you live to purchase a weapon (YES OR NO): ");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String name = sc.next();


   if (name.equals("yes")){
       System.out.println("Select Your Weapon \n axe \n bat \n sword : \n  ");

       Scanner wc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String weapon = wc.next();
       int minDmg = axeMinDmg;

    if(weapon.equals("axe")){
     int minDmg = axeMinDmg;
   } else {
       System.out.println();
} // close if statement
```

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to define the variable outside of the if statement to be able to use it outside.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, variables are defined within a scope. Here the scope is the if block. so if you declare it outside the if block, it will be available in the enclosing method scope.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the integer outside the if statement:

```
 int minDmg;
 if(weapon.equals("axe")){
     minDmg = axeMinDmg;
 } else {
     System.out.println();
 System.out.println("Can access variable: " + minDmg);
```

Comment: is there a way to declare global variable to access the variables with the scope

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Note that this won't compile: `minDmg` isn't definitely assigned in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a variable to outside of if-else block, you can use [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) which represented by the `:` operator.

For example, the standard if-else Java expression:

```
int money;
if (shouldReceiveBonus()) {
    price = 100;
}
else {
    price = 50;
}
```

With ternary operator is equivalent to:

```
int money = shouldReceiveBonus() ? 100 : 50;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int minDmg = 0; // outside of if statement.
```

Hii, I had same problem with if statement and after this i solved my problem.
in this problem you have to declare the variable outside the loop and if statement and this this null value at the time of initialise.

```
int minDmg = 0;
```

Comment: You can't assign the value `null` to an `int` variable...

Comment: yes i cant give a value null to an int but it not showing me error and working fine, and i can assign it zero;

Comment: No, that code really *will* show an error. It should show an error of "incompatible types: `<null>` cannot be converted to int". I don't know what you're compiling, but this code *will not compile* in regular Java.